# Laravel: is it possible for middleware to accept route input?

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware, laravel-permission

What I want to achieve is, I have audience in a few countries. I also have editors in different country.

For example, editor in US can only edit & view posts in [US](http://example.com/us/posts), editor in [Hong Kong](http://example.com/hk/posts) not allowed to view US posts.

```
Route::get('{country}/posts', [
    'uses' => 'CountryController@posts',
    'middleware' => ['permission:view posts,{country}'], <------- SEE HERE
]);
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

P/S: I'm using [Spatie laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, but I use this lines of code in a middleware:

```
$country = $request->route('country'); // gets 'us' or 'hk'
```

This method of `Request` returns the route segment.

Comment: `$request->route('country')`  why deal with segments, its a route parameter

Comment: You're right. this way can achieve the task too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to create another middleware, something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CountryCheck
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // The method `getEnabledCountries` returns an array 
        // with the countries enabled for the user
        if(in_array($request->route('country'), Auth::user()->getEnabledCountries())) {
           return $next($request);
        }

        // abort or return what you prefer

    }
}
```

Anyway... the `country` parameter is useless in my advice if the user can see only posts from his country... If you already know the user locale and you already have this rule... why you have to made another check?

In my opinion it's better to create a route like `Route::get('posts')` and inside the controller load the posts related to the user's country... Something like:

`Post::where('locale', '=', Auth::user()->locale())->get()`

or with a scope:

`Post::whereLocale(Auth::user()->locale())->get()`

Comment: Thanks, but `$request->route('country')` is good enough for me. I have idea how to do it already